# Hadoop Map Reduce read a text file

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm trying to write a MapReduce program that can read an input file and write the output to another text file. I'm planning to use the BufferedReader class for this. But I don't really know how to use it in a MapReduce program.

How can I write a code snippet for it?

P.S. I'm totally new to Hadoop and MapReduce programming.

Comment: Till now what you tried?And what you are tryng to implement. please be specific. Do you want to read an input file from user and write the output to HDFS? Can you explain a little more.

Comment: @SreeVeni Ok here it is. I want to read a text file using BufferedReader. And I want to write the output to either HDFS (preferably) or write the output to another text file. I haven't really tried anything yet. But that's what I basically want to do. I've looked over the internet for sample code snippets but couldn't find what answers my question. Can you help me here?

Comment: One more clarification Do you want to read text file from HDFS?

Comment: @SreeVeni I'm not that familiar with the HDFS and how it works. But I'm trying to write the program in Eclipse IDE. I've already setup Hadoop in Eclipse.

Comment: Ok then it will be nice if you try to read a file from HDFS.Will update with the code

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Below code helps you to read a file from HDFS and display the content in console

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

public class Cat{
    public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception{
        try{
            Path pt=new Path("hdfs:/path/to/file");//Location of file in HDFS
            FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(pt)));
            String line;
            line=br.readLine();
            while (line != null){
                System.out.println(line);
                line=br.readLine();
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Driver

```
public class ReadFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = new Job(conf, "Read a File");


        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        if (fs.exists(new Path(args[1])))
            fs.delete(new Path(args[1]), true);
        job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        job.setJarByClass(ReadFile.class);     
        job.waitForCompletion(true);
    }

}
```

Mapper

```
public class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    public void setup(Context context) throws IOException{
        Path pt=new Path("hdfs:/path/to/file");//Location of file in HDFS
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(pt)));
        String line;
        line=br.readLine();
        while (line != null){
            System.out.println(line);
            line=br.readLine();
        }
    }
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      //as your wish
        }
    }
}
```

Above code helps you to read a text file from HDFS.

Comment: Thank you for the code snippet. But I tried this. What I want is to read a text file in a map-reduce style program. i.e., using mapper and reducer classes.

Comment: Do you know who to read a text file in a map-reduce style program? Because that's what I need to do. It would be of great help if you can tell me how to do that. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Thank you so much. I used the code you provided, modified it according to my needs and the program works now. Thank you! :)

Comment: @UnmeshaSreeVeni This is exactly what I was looking for. Big Data newbie here! Thanks.

Comment: how can I do the same in reducer instead of mapper?

Comment: Why you are passing the path two time:
1- in         Path pt=new Path("hdfs:/path/to/file");//Location of file in HDFS
2- in         FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));   
are these the same path?
how to specify the on in Setup() class

Comment: That is an answer for the users next doubt..You can use the same in reducer as well

Comment: Both are different path. In driver it is the input file and in setup it is a cached file for further processing.

Comment: What constitutes a line in the mapper? Is it everything up to the newline character?

Comment: Yes it is till the new line