# How to use common data in MapReduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I want to load data in memory and have each Mapper use these data.

How do i do it?

Should I just use the setup method in Mapper?
Then, will each Mapper be able to use a common data in once the data is loaded ?

Comment: this link might be help full,please look into this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26209773/hadoop-map-reduce-read-a-text-file

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is exactly the way to go.

You read the stuff on `setup()` and keep it in your tasks memory.