# Multiple Input Files In one Mapper Class Hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

So,I am trying to code FP-Tree algorithm in MapReduce Paradigm,
for creating an frequent item set list , i have the following problem :

***Input:***

File1.txt (Contains all the transactions)

```
123 452 221 12 
45 76 987 
77 76 123 354 

[Each Line contains items Bought in one Transaction]
```

File2.txt (Contains Items which are bought in descending order)

```
12    123

6     221

5     77

4     354

[Count] [Item Id]
```

***Output :***

```
output.txt

123 221  
123 77 354 

[2nd transaction is eliminated]
```

**Items according to their count are taken in ( descending ), others are deleted**

**Is it possible to take both File1.txt and File2.txt into one mapper class ? because this will solve my problem**

Or is there any way to perform this operation in another way ?

*Any help is appreciated.*

Answer (score 0):

look into mapreduce distributed cache example.may be help full

http://myhadoopexamples.com/2014/04/16/hadoop-map-side-join-with-distributed-cache-example/

read the file in setup method.the above link will give good guidance.

[Hadoop Map Reduce read a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26209773/hadoop-map-reduce-read-a-text-file)

Comment: Distributed cache will be useful only when one of the files size is small which can fit inside RAM.

Answer (score 0):

You can read multiple files in one MR program. But each file should have a mapper class separately. Since both of your input files are different, the read logic varies for both of these. You can have two mappers one for each, and the output of this should have the same KEY and passed to reducer.

[You can refer to distributed cache.](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html)